# Populate field value based on external API response

Tags: nodes, hooks

My custom Drupal 10 module takes the value of an address field submitted by the user during node creation, sends that to an external API, and then fills a taxonomy term reference field based on the decoded JSON response and logic that matches to the corresponding term. (Might add more fields and potentially APIs in the future).

I have this working but encountered an issue in that because this implements "hook_node_presave", the code is not executed when previewing a node. I'm fairly new to building modules in Drupal so I am now questioning whether there is a better approach to fill this need. Is there an easy fix for this or do I need to re-architect the module? A consideration that comes to mind is perhaps the API call should be triggered from the node edit page - meaning provide the user a button to click and then give a success/failure notice but I am not sure where to begin.

Any guidance is truly appreciated!

Here is the code for the function in question, in case that's helpful:

```
function neighborhood_taxonomy_node_presave($node) {
  // Check if the node has an address.
  if (isset($node->field_address) && $node->field_address instanceof FieldItemListInterface) {
    // Get the address value from the node.
    $address = $node->get('field_address')->getString();

    // Get the current value of the neighborhood field.
    $currentNeighborhood = $node->field_neighborhood->target_id;

    // Bypass API call if we are updating the node without changing the address or reverting the node to a prior revision.
    $isUpdatedNode = !$node->isNew() && $node->original && $address === $node->original->get('field_address')->getString() && !empty($currentNeighborhood);
    $reverted = $node->original && $node->original->isDefaultRevision() && !$node->isDefaultRevision();

    if ($isUpdatedNode || $reverted) {
      \Drupal::logger('neighborhood_taxonomy')->info('Bypassing API call for node @nid.', [
        '@nid' => $node->id(),
      ]);
      return;
    }

    // Retrieve the neighborhood from the API
    $neighborhoodData = getNeighborhood($address);

    if ($neighborhoodData !== false) {
      $neighborhood = $neighborhoodData['neighborhood'];

      // Get all term in the Neighborhoods vocabulary.
      $vid = 'neighborhoods';
      $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term');
      $query->condition('vid', $vid);
      // Add an access check to the entity query.
      $query->accessCheck(TRUE);
      $tids = $query->execute();

      // Load all the terms and their field_neighborhood_id values.
      $terms = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::loadMultiple($tids);

      $matching_tid = null;

      foreach ($terms as $term) {
        // Load the field_neighborhood_id values for the term.
        $field_neighborhood_id = $term->get('field_neighborhood_id')->getValue();

        // Check for a match based on the neighborhood ID.
        $matching_values = array_column($field_neighborhood_id, 'value');
        if (in_array($neighborhood['id'], $matching_values)) {
          $matching_tid = $term->id();
          break;
        }

        // Check for a match based on neighborhood name.
        $term_name = $term->getName();
        if (strcasecmp($neighborhood['text'], $term_name) === 0) {
          $matching_tid = $term->id();
          break;
        }
      }

      $node->field_neighborhood->target_id = $matching_tid;

      // Log the neighborhood retrieval event.
      \Drupal::logger('neighborhood_taxonomy')->info('Set term for node @nid: @term', [
        '@nid' => $node->id(),
        '@term' => $term->getName(),
      ]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems you may prefer to use Drupal’s AJAX API for this.

Comment: @cilefen thank you for your response. I am looking into that and hopefully I'll be able to make this work.